# Mocking Google Analytics v4

Tags: android, unit-testing, google-analytics

I'm trying to test my code that depends on [Google Analytics SDK v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/).

Specifically I'm trying to mock `com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker` with [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

`Tracker tracker = Mockito.mock(Tracker.class);` yields [this error](http://pastebin.com/S6GkBbrX).

Are there any approaches to take? The only thing I can think of is to create my own wrapper.

Comment: any update on this ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code snipped at fault is `Tracker.class` - as this will instantiate the class, which in turn throws the `VerifyError`. This is not an issue with your code, but is a limitation of Google Play Services. The issue has been reported [in the Robolectric project](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1186) and [here](https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test/issues/69).

I used the solution provided in the second link by SuperJugy, by inserting the following to the bottom of my Gradle build file:

```html
tasks.withType(Test) {
  test {
    // set JVM arguments for the test JVM(s)
    jvmArgs '-XX:-UseSplitVerifier'
  }
}
```

To get it working in Android Studio I had to add the VM Option `-noverify` to my test build configuration.

I think you may be able to work-around the problem using a wrapper, so long as the wrapper code never instantiates the `Tracker` class. However this may not be easy (or possible?), please let me know if end up going down this path and succeed!

Comment: You have to change it to `jvmArgs '-noverify'` in the gradle build